# Column header identifier in GridViewColumnHeader.Click (WPF)

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, onclick, columnheader

I have a ListView for personal information:

```
<ListView GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click" x:Name="personListView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="{x:Static resource:PersonGridViewColumns.Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" Header="{x:Static resource:PersonGridViewColumns.Age}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nationality}" Header="{x:Static resource:PersonGridViewColumns.Nationality}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The column headers are bound to a resource so that they can be localised. When the user clicks on a column header the GridViewColumnHeader.Click fires. Inside that method I can see the content (name) of the header and get an idea of which one was clicked:

```
private void GridViewColumnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string column = ((GridViewColumnHeader)e.OriginalSource).Column.Header.ToString()

    switch (column)
    {
        case "Name":
            DoSomethingNameRelated();

            break;
        case "Age":
            DoSomethingAgeRelated();

            break;
        case "Nationality":
            DoSomethingNationalityRelated();

            break;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that it only works as long as the user has it's UI in English. I tried switching on the resource itself (e.g. PersonGridViewColumns.Name) but that won't compile because it's not a constant.

I need to know which column header has been clicked to take the appropriate action. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

The GridViewColumnHeader Header property is of type object, so you could create a class that represents a column heading. Override its ToString() method to return the localised header text, and add some kind of "ColumnId" property that your click event handler can utilise.

You can then create an instance of this class per column and expose them either as separate properties (if you only have a few columns), or as a collection, and bind to their respective column's `Header` property in the XAML.

Comment: Sounds rather confusing.